# Absolute positioned link not clickable except for a small space on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, absolute

I have a Lity anchor link that should pop up a modal containing a Youtube video. The odd thing is that this works completely fine on Chrome desktop, but on Safari and Chrome mobile the link is not clickable minus a small area. I've tried various z-indexing, various pointer-events, and tried removing the absolute positioning altogether yet it's still not clickable on mobile.

I've added borders to show where the clickable area vs not clickable area is. The blue outside the red/green borders allows the modal to pop out. Inside the red/green it is not clickable.

Again this is only on Safari and Chrome mobile browser, everything is fine on desktop.

Here's the HTML structure

```
<div class="featured-video">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_XXXXXX" data-lity="" class="videoLink">
        <img data-src="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/XXXXXX/hqdefault.jpg" alt="product video" class="videoImage lazyloaded" src="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/_R1CnAi4PKM/hqdefault.jpg">
        <span class="yt-thumb-button">.</span>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Here's my CSS/SCSS

```
.featured-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 1px solid blue;

    .videoLink {
        
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        z-index: 101;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid limegreen;
        pointer-events: auto;

    }
}

.yt-thumb-button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    // z-index: 1;
    background: url(https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-za3wv/product_images/uploaded_images/youtube-grey-play.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 20%;
    color: transparent !important;
    pointer-events: none;

    border: 1px solid red;

    &:hover {
        opacity: .4;
        transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    }
}
```

[Clickable Area Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUC6.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

> The `z-index` in the `featured-video` is greater than your button class. Set the `z-index` value of the `button` to 999.

Comment: So the button is purely cosmetic and shouldn't have to be clicked to activate the anchor modal. I made the z-index 999 just to test it out but it still has the same behavior. I even removed the button entirely and the behavior is the same.